# I'm having problems for delating all the documents from an index in elasticsearch without deleting the index

Tags: elasticsearch

curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/index-consumo_react_mysql/_doc/_query" -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'

error:

{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delete_by_query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/<index-name>/_delete_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the Content-type header and you also need to change the endpoint to `_delete_by_query`:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:9200/index-consumo_react_mysql/_delete_by_query" -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'
```

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [DELETE /index-consumo_react_mysql/_doc/_query] does not support having a body"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [DELETE /index-consumo_react_mysql/_doc/_query] does not support having a body"},"status":400}

Comment: I proved with that before and it gave me these error.

Comment: Oh, which version are you running?

Comment: 7.12.1 version .

Comment: See my updated answer, the endpoint you're using is not correct